# iOS8 Today Widget - Change title and add stuff to default

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension

I've got the default Hello World today widget attached to one of my apps, however I can't figure out how to change the title displayed next to the app icon, or seemingly affect the contents of the view controller. I've tried adding a button, with an action to change the label text - that doesn't appear, and in IB I tried changing the text colour of "Hello World" but to no seeming affect.

No real code to show as its just the example with a button action and a few outlets connected to the storyboard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change the `CFBundleDisplayName` in your `info.plist` file.

I'm not sure what you mean by adding button to the label text. You can't change the colour of this text.

Comment: All I meant was when the button is clicked, the "hello world" would change to another string. It seems too buggy to use atm, at least thats the feeling on the dev forums.

Comment: @user1710566 the label inside the view controller itself can change, but the name of the app can't. Feel free to open another question about that, and post some code.

Comment: Make sure you update the string in `InfoPlist.strings` as well—it will override what's in `Info.plist`. I, uh, definitely did not just waste an hour before I finally realized that. I also had to open Activity Monitor and tell Notification Center to quit to get the name to update immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the info.plist inside your app extension files. Change the bundle display name. Which is "ShareAction" in the screen shot.

[image]